# Turn enumerate into panel table of contents in pdfscreen

Tags: table-of-contents, presentations, pdfscreen

I'm trying to get the following:
I have several files (many) containing lists numbered from 1 to 25, each with A), B), C). Using the package `pdfscreen` I want to turn them into a presentation and would like the right panel to show the 25 items (in a 5x5 grid) but not how to add entries for each item to `pdfscreen` as the display panel in a 5x5 grid to the right.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate{parsep=4pt,partopsep=4pt,topsep=4pt,labelsep=3pt, leftmargin=*,itemsep=2pt}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*)}
\usepackage[screen,panelright,code,paneltoc,sectionbreak]{pdfscreen}
\begin{screen}
 \margins{.65in}{.65in}{.65in}{.65in}
 \screensize{6.25in}{8in}
 \changeoverlay
\end{screen}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ejercicios 1 al 5}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Uno
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Dos
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Tres
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Cuatro
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Cinco
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ejercicios 6 al 10}
\item Seis
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Siete
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Ocho
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Nueve
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ejercicios 10 al 15}
\item Diez
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Once
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Doce
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Trece
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Catorce
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Quince
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ejercicios 16 al 20}
\item Diez y 6
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Diez y 7
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Diez y 8
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Diez y 9
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Veinte
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ejercicios 21 al 25}
\item Veinte y 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Veinte y 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Veinte y 3
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Veinte y 4
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\item Veinte y 5
\begin{enumerate}
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I want this in the right panel

```
1  6   11  16  21
2  7   12  17  22
3  8   13  18  23
4  9   14  19  24
5  10  15  20  25
```

if this is possible using `pdfscreen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enumitem package allows very flexible formatting of all sorts of lists. I'd try that before other options. To make a presentation out of the whole mess I'd use beamer (you can ask it to split frames (i.e., slides) on its own, no need to split by hand).

OTOH, in a presentation you have little space (and time!) to get the point across, an endless list of bullet points nested three deep will make your audience's eyes glass over after the second slide... try to find a better way to summarize the data (a graph perhaps? In his delightful "Programming Pearls" Jon Bentley discusses some impressive graphs for showing the complex relations among several variables).